# What will be the value of k?

Tags: logarithms

I was solving a problem and in the middle of that problem I encountered an equation from which value of k was needed to be figured out. What will be the value of k in terms of n ? Also how to find it ?

$$ n^{\frac{1}{2^k}} = 1 $$

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible... except for $n=1$.
Otherwise it would mean that $\dfrac{1}{2^k}=0$...